# grep command in unix for getting particular string

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have `test.txt` file, which contains the lines below:

```
Period 1
Period 2
Period 3
........
.
.
.
Period 10
Period 11
Period 12
.
.
.
```

Likewise I have 18 rows inside the `test.txt` file.

Now I need to create the new file from this `test.txt` such that when I give 'Period 1', it should show only "Period 1" row alone in new file.

I am facing issue here: when I'm trying to do `grep "Period 1" > newfile.txt`, it gives all the period which start with "Period 1", "Period 10", "Period 11", and so on.

Comment: TRY with "Period 1 " space at the end.

Comment: Or use a regex with grep. Match the end of line character if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use grep with general expression, which should match the beginning and the end of the line:

```
grep -e '^Period 1$' > newfile.txt
```

The regular expression here means: "<the beginning of the line>Period<space>1<the end of the line>"

If you're not sure about format, you may use the expression, which will match any number of spaces (or any other whitespaces) in the middle:

```
egrep '^Period\s*1$' # egrep is synonym for `grep -E`, where -E stands for extended regexps
```

For further reading on regular expressions in `grep`: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux